# How to check if any control in a reactive form has value in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a form in which there are 4-5 different types of control. 
On certain user action, I need to know if any of the controls have any value in it and it can happen on any state of the form - be it pristine or dirty. I cannot rely on the form states for this.
cCan't even loop through since this.myForm.controls isn't an array type. Also this.myForm.value is always an 'object' even though no values for controls in it.

Here is the form creation code, if that helps:

```
this.searchForm = this.fb.group({
            'ids': this.fb.control([], multipleInputValidator(2)),
            'locationName': this.fb.control([], Validators.minLength(2)),
            'accountCodes': this.fb.control([], multipleInputValidator(2)),
            'regionCodes': this.fb.control([], multipleInputValidator(2)),
            'city': this.fb.control([], Validators.minLength(2)),
            'typeIds': this.fb.control([]),
            'centreIds': this.fb.control([]),
            'siteCodes': this.fb.control([]),
            'statusCode': this.fb.control([]),
            'from': this.fb.control([]),
            'to': this.fb.control([])
        });
```

Answer (score 6):

```
console.log(!!this.myForm.get('mycontrol').value);
```

Comment: I need for all controls. can't even loop through since this.myForm.controls isn't a array type. Also this.myForm.value is always an 'object' even though no values for controls in it.

Comment: Sorry, if the question is less detailed for you, but I thought it is a generic question and no code is required. Not sure what kind of code you are looking for.

Comment: Alright, edited the question with form creation code, HTML is implicit I'd believe. Clarifying the question, is there a way to know if any of the form controls have value in it. Not a single one, but all of them.

Comment: You can use `this.searchForm.values` and check if any of the properties contains a value. You can use `Object.keys()` to get the properties of the resulting `values` object.

Comment: I would recommend `Object.values(form.controls).some(({ value }) => !!value || value === 0)`, a variation on the suggested keys approach that is a bit more direct and considers 0 a valid value.

Comment: The answer could gain a lot if it would consist of at least a brief reasoning instead of a comment-less code line

Answer (score 5):

Here's a quick way you can do this check using [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

```
Object.keys(this.searchForm.value).some(k => !!this.filterForm.value[k])
```

This will check the properties in the `value` object that represents your form state, and return `true` if any of those properties are truthy, i.e. have a value.

Comment: wouldn't `Object.values` make more sense here rather than getting the key and going back to the value?

Comment: @bryan60 yes, that's a good point. `Object.values` would make more sense, BUT it's not supported by IE, whereas `Object.keys` is.

Comment: eh IMO if you don't HAVE to support IE anymore, you shouldn't. if you're one of the unfortunate who must (or just wants to), you should polyfill instead of hamstringing you entire project. Angular makes it easy enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
checkFormChanges() {
this.searchForm.valueChanges
  .filter(() => this.searchForm.valid)
  .map((value) => {
    for (let key in value) {
      if (value[key]) {
        switch (key) {
          case 'whatever': //do something
        }
      }
    }
  }).subscribe();
```

}

This will loop through a form group and check the valid values of each control, then you can do what you want with them in the cases.

Hope it helps.